# Showmount command not found in Linux kali 4.19.0 - Having trouble installing nfs-common

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I get the following error while tring to install `nfs-common`.

```
Package 'nfs-common' has no installation candidate
```

Related posts also talk about install `nfs-common` which gives the above mentioned error.

I am trying to install `nfs-common` because the `showmount` command was not found in Kali linux, and I need it for my ongoing OSCP Certification work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean

Comment: Was finally able to get showmount to work by changing the repositories in sources.list file.

Comment: You can add that as an answer yourself. Give plenty of details of how you did this so that it may help others in the future.